# How to display only new image that i added to the gallery in ios

Tags: iphone

viewcontroller.m

```
 __block NSMutableArray *tmpAssets = [@[] mutableCopy];   
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [ViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];  


[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup      *group, BOOL *stop)        
{   
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) 
    {   
        if(result)   
        {   
            [tmpAssets addObject:result];   
        }   
    }];   
    self.assets = tmpAssets;   
    [self.collectionView reloadData];  
}  
failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error loading images %@", error);  
}];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way that i have followed:

Store Photos name in database. Photos name can be get from the object: asset.defaultRepresentation.filename

We need to check the file name in the database. If we get any record for it, then we can say that the photo is old photo. If we didn't get any photo name from the database, then we can day the photo is newly added in the gallery. We collect all this new photos and shown on the screen.

I have some code for checking new photo, it may help you:

```
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"photoName == %@", asset.defaultRepresentation.filename];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
            NSError *error;

            NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContextLocalForBackgroundThread executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

            if ([fetchedObjects count] == 0) {
                // New Photo
                // You can add photos object in your array      
            } else {
                // Old Photo 
            }
```

Hope, it will help you,

:)

Comment: How To Get The Image Name.Because i am new to xcode...Help

Comment: Get Image Name from asset.defaultRepresentation.filename. It will be unique.